# How to create batch file that executes several sql files

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, batch-file

I have several sql files that need to execute every day.

I want realize it with batch file.

Assume that *.bat file and *.sql files in one folder

I new in working with *.bat files.

Yes, possible duplicate, but I found many answers, and I don't understand all off them.

I'm working with mySQL, dbforge, windows 7.

And i have this string in *.bat file:

```
echo mysql --host=localhost --user=myuser --password=mypass --database=dbName
```

But nothin happened, if I execute it.

My sql query:

```
INSERT INTO s_g01(customer_id, city)
(SELECT t1.customer_id,dr.caption 
  FROM devls.dict_regions dr
  INNER JOIN devls.adm_terminal at
    ON dr.id = at.region_id
  INNER JOIN devls.transaction t1
    ON at.id = t1.terminal_id AND t1.reason_id = 6) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE city = dr.caption
```

Comment: Echo just dumps out does run ... ditch echo part

Answer (score 0):

update below line in your batch file and schedule this batch file by scheduler.

```
cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"

mysql -h server_ip -u<usernane> -p<password> db_name < script.sql

pause
exit
```

script.sql file should be same path where is batch file else you need to give comlete path with script.sql filename.

Comment: I don't know server_ip or i can write localhost?

Comment: if mysql is on your local machine then you can put localhost but if you are using remote server then you have to put server_ip.

Comment: As I understand you run 1 *.sql file, I need to run all files in folder.

Comment: I execute my ***.bat** file but it also not working. May be my sql syntax is wrong? I edit my question, added my sql query.

Comment: step1: execute your query from any gui tool and check if query is fine, step2: Now execute given command for batch file from command line and check if you are able to execute it. Step3: If you have succeed in step2 then use step3, so that can be find out that issue is related with batch file or else.

Comment: @ I check for your step1 and step2. And batch file creates file devls, but file is empty!

Comment: you need to prepare batch file as I updated in my post, change mysql path  as per your system..in which system you are executing batch file mysql utility should be at path as mentioned...

Comment: In my computer, I haven't this link: "c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin". I'm working with dbForge for Mysql. Database is remote. What is wrong?